# Geocoder not working, cant get long and lat to display in alert box

Tags: geocoding, google-geocoder

I am new to javascript and geocoding and I'm trying to learn how to use the two together.

I have created a form to take the users input post code and I then have the code to convert it to long and lat. I have included and alert to show the postcode so as I know how much has worked (more to help me teach myself)

It returns the alert box with the input post code but nothing else!?

I would like it show the long and lat in alert box's. Once I know I have the long and lat I will be looking into adding them into a MySQL table, but I will worry about that once I know I have retreived the values

Here is the code:

```
    <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function getPostCode() {
var postcode = document.getElementById("pcode").value;
    alert("Your Post Code is: " + postcode);
var gc = new google.maps.Geocoder();
gc.geocode({'address' : postcode}, function(results, status){ 
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        alert( "latitude : " + results[0].geometry.location.lat() ); 
        alert( "longitude : " + results[0].geometry.location.lng() ); 
} else {
    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
}
}); 
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <form name="search" METHOD="GET" onsubmit="return getPostCode()">
 Post Code: <input type="text" name="pcode" />
 <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be much appreciated

----------------Update-------------------

Matt thanks for you help so far, I have now edited the code to output the value to paragraph tags and removed the alert box, but it still wont display the lat and long, is my geocode code correct? It pulls through the post code but not the lat and long or error.

```
    <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function getPostCode() {
var postcode = document.getElementById("pcode").value;
    var postcode = "Your Post Code is: " + postcode;
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML=postcode;
var mygc = new google.maps.Geocoder();
mygc.geocode({'address' : postcode}, function(results, status){ 
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML=lat; 
        var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
document.getElementById("long").innerHTML=long; 
} else {
    var err = "Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status;
document.getElementById("error").innerHTML=err;
}
}); 
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

 <form name="search">
 Post Code: <input type="text" name="pcode" />
 <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="getPostCode()" />
 </form>

<p id="p1"></p>
<p id="long"></p>
<p id="lat"></p>
<p id="error"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Alerts are blocking. Try removing the first alert that shows the postcode.

Comment: What do you mean alerts are blocking. Thanks

Comment: Alerts block the Javascript thread in browsers. Meaning, a browser displays an alert and execution is paused until the alert is dismissed. I've seen this cause problems with callbacks and other stuff before, especially when timing is concerned. I don't know why exactly, but try using console.log instead. It won't interrupt the execution of your code.

Comment: I have added more code above but still cant seem to return the long and lat values!? Do you need an APi key for geocode v3? As far as i am aware you needed it for v2 but not v3?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're doing since you say you're using v3 of the API but you don't need to construct google.maps.geocoder for v3 -- that's a version 2 thing. Besides that, you aren't even including Google's Javascript onto your page with a `<script>` tag. Look at your Javascript console. It's probably throwing an error.

To geocode with v3, just make requests to this URL, for example:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false

The response is ready-to-parse JSON. No need for classes, instantiation, etc.

Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: I think i'm getting lost between versions, i've been looking at so many tutorials! What I would like is for the user to input their post code and then the long and lat be displayed. The display is for my benefit and understanding, once I can see that I will be looking to add this to a mySQL database for reporting purposes. The bit where i'm getting lost is actually getting hold of the long and lat coordinates. Could you advise me how I could do this, or point me in the right direction.

Comment: I only started learning Javascript and geocoding about a couple if Weeks ago so my skills are still very basic. I've already had to put it down for a couple if days as I was getting confused!

Comment: Okay, I see. No problem. Take a look at [Google's simple geocoding example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple). View the source of that page to see how it's done. It's closer to what you are doing here. Further, learn how to use a debugging console. For example, if you use Chrome, press F12 (or Cmd+Shift+I on a Mac). Hope this helps.

Comment: I've had a look at that example and cant see where my code is going wrong. Ive even copied the code from your link and then uploaded it onto my domain and I am not getting the map come up!? Am I meant to ref google API in some way or something? Ive tried the F12 in chrome and cant seem to understand that either?

Comment: I should also add, i have been looking all over the net and have tried several bits of code and i cant seem to get any of them to work. Thanks for your help so far

Comment: That magic `<script>` tag which has the `src` attribute is what makes it possible. Make sure to include that before your other Javascript, and look at the console. What is it telling you?